# How to make routing secure in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing

I have done normal routing. Lets say my url is http://dev.something.com/home. Now when I put http://dev.something.com/?_anything it also opens the same link. How can we eliminate it? Or is it normal to be like this? I am new in codeigniter. Any kind of help are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you can try this  : `$route['home(:any)'] = 'home/$1'`;

Comment: Can you share your route config?

Comment: @PeterM okay I have default_controller like this $route['default_controller'] = "home"; . Now when I put my url say localhost/rpgtest it opens the home page. But if I also do http://localhost/rpgtest/?_djfvdjf, It opens the same home page. Can we stop that anyhow?

Comment: So you mean "rpgtest" is your controller, right? Which means it is actually working as expected, since you are still calling the same controller by using "rpgtest" again in your URL, but only changing the parameter after the controller (which ideally indicates the function, which defaults to the `index()` function in the controller if the specified function is not found)

Comment: The default controller is used when there are no URL segments passed after the main/root domain name e.g. [http://dev.something.com/](http://dev.something.com/)